# Dark sunken spots on green tomatoes

Tags: tomatoes

I’ve discovered these dark, sunken spots on my green tomatoes. The plant looks healthy so I don’t think it’s blight. It’s only on the fruit. Not blossom end rot either. It’s not on all of them, just a few. Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 1):

An animal or insect is eating a hole in the skin, and then the heat from the sun shrivels the edges of the hole. Did that happen over night?
Planting mint or basil with tomato deters some pests that like to eat tomatoes.